# jQuery function passing parameters

Tags: jquery

```js
var abc = '5';
$('#test').click(meraFunc(abc));
function meraFunc(abc)
{
  alert(abc);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="test" value="testMe">
```

when I load the page, alert pops up showing '5' [I havent yet clicked the button]. And when I click the button, nothing happens. Is this the right way to pass the arguments in jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap it with an anonymous function ([jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BPv3n/1/)):

```
j('#test').click(function() {
    meraFunc(abc);
});
```

Comment: Perfectoooo!.. Acceping in 10 mins.. [SO rules... :)]

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that on this line:

```
j('#test').click(meraFunc(abc));
```

You are *calling* meraFunc and then passing whatever it returns (undefined) to the `.click()` function. This is why the alert pops up immediately.

You need to pass a function reference to `.click()` which would look like this:

```
j('#test').click(meraFunc);   // no parens after meraFunc
```

But then how to pass parameters? Wrap the call in another function as follows:

```
j('#test').click(function() {
   meraFunc(abc);
});
```

Note that the anonymous function I've added also has no `()` parens after it so it doesn't get called immediately. Then when an actual click event occurs the anonymous function will be called and it will in turn call your function with a parameter as `meraFunc(abc)`.

Answer (score 0):

@Umesh251: I am aware of the fact that you have got the valid solution from @heikkim but just want to explain the abnormal behavior of your existing code.

```
$('#test').click(meraFunc(abc));
```

You were getting an alert on page-load because you were not binding a click event to `#test`. Thats why there were no alert when you manually click the test button.

Comment: That's not quite right. It is calling `meraFunc` immediately due to the `()` after the function name, and then it passes the return value from `meraFunc()` (which happens to be undefined) to the `.click()` function. This does not invoke the click event, though obviously it doesn't bind a handler either since you can't bind undefined.

Comment: @nnnnnn: thats what I said. Just forgot to mention that `meraFunc(abc)` does not return anything. What exactly happens here is it neither binds nor calls click event.

http://jsfiddle.net/BPv3n/2/

Comment: The part I objected to was where you said it was "invoking the click _event_" (my emphasis).

Comment: @nnnnnn: yeah, i should remove that line. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
Var abc= 5;
$('#test').click(function());
function meraFunc(abc)
{
    alert(abc);
}
```

enjoy

Answer (score -1):

Wrap meraFunc inside anonymous function.

```
  var abc = '5';

  $('#test').click(function(){
    meraFunc(abc)
  });

  function meraFunc(abc)
  {
    alert(abc);
  }
```